# How to access object of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I am new to jquery and trying something and got stuck at it,
My problem is i have object with array in it i am not able to find the way to access that array from the object

```
 //My object is shown in debugging time is as below 

  cache:object 
   0001-:Array[2]
         0:value1,
         1:value2
   _prto_:object
```

and i want to access the `value1` and `value2` from the `0001-` array from that object is there way to access that array. Any help would be great. I know with `$.each` i can loop through it and and then again access the array but is there any other way to do it.

Comment: There is a way but you should provide the code not the console/debugger message.

Comment: There's no jquery there, that's just a Javascript object.

Comment: Try out my new update.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it like, and keep in mind that you should use `bracket notation` in this context, since your keys having a starting character as a `number`.

```
cache['0001-'][0] //first element on that array
cache['0001-'][1] //second element
```

A workaround for your new requirement,

```
var cache = {'0001-' : [0,1]};
var xKeys = Object.keys(cache);

console.log(xObj[xKeys[0]][0]);
console.log(xObj[xKeys[0]][1]);
```

Comment: the name of array is dynamic it can be different each time so is there any way that i can use it using index like `cache[0][0]` i tried this but it is not working

Comment: @Curiosity It is an object so you cannot access it like an array. You should provide its `key` or you have to iterate into it by using `$.each`